# Add images in comments

Tags: discussion, comments, images

Sometimes I would like to add an image to the comment. So far, I used [postimg](https://postimages.org/), for example [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250991/array-manipulation-add-a-value-to-each-of-the-array-elements-between-two-given/251001#comment493932_251001).

To add an image in a question I see that [imgur](https://imgur.com/) is the default option.

Is imgur the recommended service to add images?

Comment: Who deleted my comment? And why my question keeps getting downvoted? This question has an high rated answer, (thanks @Glorfindel) probably useful for many. My previous comment was "Thanks anonymous downvoter". It was ironic, because after (or before) downvoting is good practice to leave a comment, but the anonymous downvoter didn't do that. Now there are two anonymous downvoters. It's my first question in meta, I'd like to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "Thanks" isn't really accepted as a genuine comment, much less so as snark.If you want feedback, ask - don't snipe. Although, an appeal to pre-existing downvoters would likely go unheeded since they aren't likely to revisit the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is. I usually start writing a new answer, upload the image there, and cut/paste the link to the comment. Stack Exchange has its own 'channel' on imgur (that's why there is `.stack.` in the URLs), so you can count on that even if imgur somehow would stop hosting images in the future, Stack Exchange will migrate them automatically to a new hosting provider. Also, users in a corporate network where imgur and other image hosters are blocked sometimes have convinced their administrators to make an exception for `i.stack.imgur.com` since that is vital for Stack Exchange.